# Clean Code best practices, should I validate data inside function or in the caller?

Tags: c#, code-cleanup

Check this function:

```
private string function(string currentRegion)
{
    if (string.isNullOrEmpty(currentRegion)) return;// Is it the best practice to validate it inside the function?

    return doSomething();
}
```

Or

```
if (string.isNullOrEmpty(region)) result = function(region); // Or here?
```

Or maybe `both?`

Because if validate inside function so which string be return if invalid?

Because if caller validate => "I'm the function" I must validate it!

Because if use both ways, maybe redundant code?

Comment: Imagine you have to call your function `function` 10 times. Would you do the validation check 10 times i.e. caller side or do it once in your function? Your function knows what it needs to work correctly, you can't expect your caller code to know what the function needs.

Comment: What's more important is how you represent the return value. How will you know if it was valid or invalid in the caller if you delegate the validation to the function?

Comment: It's common to have a separate validating function which can be very specific, maybe even needs some config. In the working function you still check some entry conditions like a string beeing non-null, otherwise you throw an exception (the developer is responsible to do the full validation before calling the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If it is the private function/method, and parameters can be checked on the caller side, checking by caller should be enought. Of course you can check inside such functions/methods too, for example for protection against mistakes made by yourself.

And, if it is any public method/function, it is strongly recomended to check parameters inside this function/method, because you can't assume that it will be called properly.

Do not believe outer word, do not believe unknown code, do not believe any other programmer, which is calling your functions/methods ;) Protection against wrong parameters can be realised by few lines of code and the cost of this protection is always less than the cost of hours spent on debugging the code and investigating, what is wrong.

Comment: A few lines of code a gazillion times...

Comment: Thanks so much, all you gave me another side to think about this and they're all helpful!